# Implementation of Pega DX API in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, pega, fiware-pegasus

I have a requirement for Android app development using Pega DX APIs. I have gone through the Pega documentation, but I'm not entirely sure about the feasibility of implementing it in Android using the Pega DX APIs. I am using XML layout for the design, not Jetpack Compose. When I searched the Pega website, I found sample SDKs for iOS, but no SDK samples were provided for Android. If anyone has any insight into implementing Pega APIs in an Android app, it would be very helpful.

Any source for the Android app implemetated using Pega DX API would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without ever knowing about this product before: 1) Focus on finding the appropriate REST APIs 2) Understand where the server lives (cloud or on-prem) With a bit of searching I found: https://docs.pega.com/bundle/dx-api/page/platform/dx-api/accessing-testing-dx-api-ver-1.html and https://docs.pega.com/bundle/dx-api/page/platform/dx-api/security-settings.html If you understand those pages, you can go back to your requester about getting a test/development environment. Good luck.